# Piping data through arbitrary functions in Clojure

Tags: clojure

I know that the `->` form can be used to pass the results of one function result to another:

```
(f1 (f2 (f3 x))) 
(-> x f3 f2 f1) ; equivalent to the line above
```

(taken from the [excellent Clojure tutorial at ociweb](http://java.ociweb.com/mark/clojure/article.html))

However this form requires that you know the functions you want to use at design time. I'd like to do the same thing, but at run time with a list of arbitrary functions.

I've written this looping function that does it, but I have a feeling there's a better way:

```
(defn pipe [initialData, functions]
  (loop [
      frontFunc (first functions)
      restFuncs (rest functions)
      data initialData ]
    (if frontFunc
      (recur (first restFuncs) (rest restFuncs) (frontFunc data) )
      data )
  ) )
```

What's the best way to go about this?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I must admit I'm really new to clojure and I might be missing the point here completely, but can't this just be done using comp and apply?

```
user> (defn fn1 [x] (+ 2 x))
user> (defn fn2 [x] (/ x 3))
user> (defn fn3 [x] (* 1.2 x))
user> (defn pipe [initial-data my-functions] ((apply comp my-functions) initial-data))
user> (pipe 2 [fn1 fn2 fn3])
2.8
```

Comment: Or without defining those functions beforehand: (pipe 2 #(+ 2 %) #(/ % 3) #(* 1.2 %))

Comment: Yep you're right, I'm new to Clojure too and hadn't come across comp yet. But what if I have a list of functions, rather than collected arguments? How do I break up the list so comp will accept it?

Comment: ...cuz without that detail, I can't use arbitrary run-time functions, and it's really just the same problem restated.

Comment: Not 100% sure what you mean with "a list of functions, rather than collected arguments"? But if I guess right: have a look at (apply). That's what apply does: it takes a list and converts that list to arguments to a function. For example: (comp [fn1 fn2 fn3]) does not work, but (apply comp [fn1 fn2 fn3]) does.

Comment: It should be noted that if non-commutativity is important, `(apply comp [fn1 fn2 fn3])` applies the pipe right-to-left. Use `(apply comp (reverse [fn1 fn2 fn3]))` to apply left-to-right.

Comment: This answer, as written, totally misses the point. You correctly sus out what the @tenpn was seeking in the second comment in this post, but that is not reflected anywhere in your answer. You've just reimplemented `->`.

You're post however does correctly answer the question (and quite nicely) if you remove the & from the function definition.

Answer (score 7):

You can do this with a plain old `reduce`:

```
(defn pipe [x fs] (reduce (fn [acc f] (f acc)) x fs))
```

That can be shortened to:

```
(defn pipe [x fs] (reduce #(%2 %1) x fs))
```

Used like this:

```
user> (pipe [1 2 3] [#(conj % 77) rest reverse (partial map inc) vec])
[78 4 3]
```

Answer (score 4):

If functions is a sequence of functions, you can reduce it using comp to get a composed function. At a REPL:

```
user> (def functions (list #(* % 5) #(+ % 1) #(/ % 3)))
#'user/my-list
user> ((reduce comp functions) 9)
20
```

apply also works in this case because comp takes a variable number of arguments:

```
user> (def functions (list #(* % 5) #(+ % 1) #(/ % 3)))
#'user/my-list
user> ((apply comp functions) 9)
20
```